# How do I stack copies of a 1D tensor in keras?

Tags: keras, tensorflow

I have a tensor `x` of shape `(5, 1)`. I would like to stack 10 copies of it so that I get a tensor of shape `(5, 10)`. In a sort, it would look like `[x|..|x]`. How to do it the keras way? I have tried the `Concatenate` layer, but I got an error.

Help is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

After many troubles with `Concatenate`, I simply did:

```py
x = Reshape((5, 1))(x)
t = ones((1, 10))
stacked_x = x @ t
```

Maths help a lot. Should have thought about it earlier.